# Why doesn't Httparty fetch the source code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I am writing an application that is supposed to fetch the source code of a page and show it.

It will be a simple JSON format, no HTML nor CSS whatsoever. So the source code of the site that I'm trying to fetch looks like this:

```
{"latitude" : "n/a","longitude" : "n/a","internalTemperature" : "n/a","light" : "n/a","distance" : "n/a" ...
```

and every time, using httparty, I get something like this:

```
#, @headers={"x-frame-options"=>["sameorigin"], "x-xss-protection"=>["1; mode=block"], "content-type"=>["text/html;charset=utf-8"], "content-length"=>["86692"], "server"=>["WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/1.9.2/2012-04-20)"], "date"=>["Wed, 09 May 2012 17:46:34 GMT"], "connection"=>["close"]}>
```

What is that type of data?, I don't understand.

I have in my erb file a line like this:

```
<%= Representative.get('http://0.0.0.0:4568/').inspect %>
```

And in my .rb file:

```
class Representative
  include HTTParty
end
```

Obviously the site that I'm reaching is on my localhost so you can't see it, but it returns a simple JSON like I showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't `inspect` the result. The result of a Httparty request is supposed to be the JSON, decoded into a hash if your URL points to a JSON document. If not, you can tell Httparty to decode to JSON explicitly.

See "[Changing Body Type To JSON Using HTTParty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154176/changing-body-type-to-json-using-httparty)".

Comment: Thank you very much. Bonus question: When i do it with out `inspect` I get the correct JSON file, but prefixed with a string `http://0.0.0.0:4568` . Do you why is that and how would i be able to lose it?