# logging a user with HTTParty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, httparty

I have a shi**y API, which returns a broken JSON after GET request with HTTParty.

GET `HTTParty.get('url/login/success/', headers: {cookie: "JSESSIONID=ID"})` returns `JSON::ParserError (765: unexpected token at)`

and response.body is

`"{\"head\":{\"apikey\":null,\"sessionid\":\"ID\",\"timestamp\":1551772335837,\"sessiontimeout\":1551775035837,\"wishlistItemsCount\":0,\"basketItemsCount\":0,\"loggedIn\":true,\"role\":\"C\"},\"data\":{\"user\":{\"profile\":{\"title\":\"Title\",\"firstname\":\"Name\",\"lastname\":\"Lastname\",\"street\":\"Street\",\"street2\":\"number\",\"postalcode\":\"code\",\"city\":\"City\",\"customerID\":\"ID\",\"customerType\":xx}},\"abandonedBasket\":false},\"messages\":[{\"code\":\"url.api.login.success\",\"statusCode\":200,\"description\":\"OK\"}]}{\"head\":{\"apikey\":null,\"sessionid\":\"ID\",\"timestamp\":1551772335841,\"sessiontimeout\":1551775035841,\"wishlistItemsCount\":0,\"basketItemsCount\":0,\"loggedIn\":true,\"role\":\"C\"},\"data\":{},\"messages\":[{\"code\":\"url.api.general.error\",\"statusCode\":500,\"description\":\"Es ist ein interner Fehler aufgetreten. Bitte versuchen sie es später noch einmal.\"}]}"`

Is there any possibility to fix the response's JSON for user to log in and use his account normally?

The alternative I have is using `curl` inside code, but I want to avoid it

Comment: So you have no control over the API itself? If so then I would report the error to the person that does as this is clearly invalid `JSON`. Second how do you know which response is correct. Is it valid or an error?

Comment: Right, no control over API. I assume that valid response is correct, since same request with curl returns valid response.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are not sending JSON data.

Check this [Changing Content-Type to JSON using HTTParty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154176/changing-content-type-to-json-using-httparty)

1. content_type
2. to_json

Comment: I do send JSON. The response's body somehow has two parts with malformed JSON

Comment: 1) do you specify content-type? 2) try to save response into json file and validate online it. 3) try to compare all headers (print debug info from httparty to console) and  same with curl and check the difference